# deprecation errors when running rspec tests after updating to rails 5.0.0

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I just upgraded an application from rails 4 to rails 5.0.0, however now when running my rspec tests I'm getting these deprecation warnings (they don't show up when running my server):

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Documents/app/config/environment.rb:5)
DEPRECATION WARNING: alias_method_chain is deprecated. Please, use Module#prepend instead. From module, you can access the original method using super. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Documents/app/config/environment.rb:5)
DEPRECATION WARNING: after_filter is deprecated and will be removed in Rails 5.1. Use after_action instead. (called from <top (required)> at /Users/Documents/app/config/environment.rb:5)
```

The alias_method_chain warning does show up twice. I'm not using neither `alias_method_chain` or `after_filter` in any of my code.

The gems are using for the test enviroment:

```
group :development do
  gem 'dotenv-rails', '2.1.1'
  gem 'byebug', '9.0.5'
  gem 'bullet', '5.2.0'
  gem 'bundler-audit', '0.5.0'
  gem 'spring', '1.7.2'
  gem 'web-console', '3.3.1'
  gem 'guard-rspec', '4.7.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '~> 2.1'
  gem 'poltergeist', '1.10.0'
  gem 'formulaic', '0.3.0'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '3.5.1'
  gem 'rspec-mocks', '3.5.0'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers', '3.1.1'
  gem 'timecop-console', '0.1.0'
  gem 'database_cleaner', '1.5.3'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.12.0'
  gem 'rails-controller-testing', '0.1.1'
end

group :development, :test do
  gem 'pry-rails', '0.3.4'
  gem 'factory_girl', '4.7.0'
  gem 'faker', '1.6.6'
  gem 'jasmine', '2.4.0'
  gem 'jasmine-ajax', '0.0.2'
end
```

I'm not using versions in my gemfile, I just included the current versions I'm using. Any clues of what's causing the deprecation warnings?

EDIT:

I found where the warnings are coming from, I'm using `wicked_pdf`, here's the [issue](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/510)

It seems it's been fixed, but I'm getting the deprecation warnings still even though I'm using the last version

Comment: What's at environment.rb:5?

Comment: Hey Carlos, would you mind giving us a sense of what you are initializing in `config/initializers`? I'm super curious what would be initializing for your test env that isn't loading for your dev environment. I imagine that one of your gems that is only in use in your test environment has the deprecated methods in it... I've done a bunch of scavenger hunting already, but to little success... I repro'd your gems in a new project, but w/o your initializers, I don't have any errors when I run `rspec spec`.

Comment: I updated the question with my spec and rails helper files, that's pretty much what I'm configuring for the test enviroment

Comment: Hey Carlos. I used your `spec_helper` and `rails_helper` files, and I still couldn't reproduce. Is there anything in your initializers that references a gem that is only in your :test group? Also, what about your test.rb environment file?

Comment: sorry, had some long long weeks working on the app. I found where the problem came from, editing the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warnings were caused by the `wicked_pdf` gem, updating to version `1.1.0` solved the [issue](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf/issues/510)